# Использование сторонних классов Java

Tags: java, gradle

Использую gradle и командную строку. Как использовать другие классы в главном пакете? Ну чтоб можно было прописать

```
import package.test;
```

Создал в директории src/main/java папки package потом test. Но gradle ругается - пишет 'package package does not exist'

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте не использовать [зарезервированные ключевые слова](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html) в идентификаторах. Думаю проблема в слове `package`.